# which ending should a vxworks script have?

Tags: vxworks

I want to execute some shell commands automatically, but I don't know in which format the scripts must be written.

.sh , .bat ....?

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Simply one command per line.  No extension needed.
You have to use the redirection operator to execute your script.

```
-> < myCommandScript
```